# What is difference between rich notification and remote notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

When I read [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html), they mention 3 types of notification: local, remote, and silent.

I understand local notification and remote and silent notification but some people ask me that.

**do you know about the rich notification in iOS?**

However, what is the difference between rich and remote notification?

thanks in advance for giving depth information about notifications in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Rich Notifications** means Notifications with **Payload** or you can say **media attachment** in notifications.

**Remote Notifications** means APNs(Apple Push Notifications) which send notification from one server to multiple devices at a time with **media attachment** or **without media attachment**.

But if we talk about **Rich Notifications** its means A notifications with media attachment or you can say payload Data.

Both Notifications Have some common per-defined steps.

1) **Apple Developer Program Membership.**

2) **Configuration of Bundle Identifier with Push Certificate.**

3) **Enable Push Notifications in Capabilities of Xcode section.**

4) **Local Server(your server or you can use firebase/pusher for
   testing) which will responsible for sending Notifications.**

Answer (score 0):

After sdk version iOS10 it is possible to send push notifications that may point to **a media file** alongside with the notification message, title and addition data.

This media file, let it be an image, will show beside the notification message when the device recieves the notification.